# Angular dialog open causes query parameters being removed on newly loaded page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, mat-dialog

I think it has something to do with how the dialog is injected so it does not know about the component tree or the routing. Which I say it's good thing if it's the case.

But it's strange the URL (query parameters bit) changes after opening dialog.

So the route is like `/abcd?a=1`. Everything is fine if I am staying in the app. But if I copy the URL, open a new page, then click the button on the page to open an [Angular CDK dialog](https://rc.material.angular.io/components/dialog/api), the query parameter part is gone.

The route becomes `/abcd`

Look at the doc, [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#properties) properties are all read-only. I tried to sync that myself by passing that from the routing component into the dialog. It didn't work.

Comment: Never had such problems, its rather an issue with your code/config

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I know the root of the problem.

But I changed my html and the problem is gone.

Basically, I have `<a>` tag with `[routerLink]="[]" (click)="doSomething()"` nested in `<li>` CdkMenuItem which is nested in `<ul>` CdkMenu

After I changed the `<li>` to button instead of this nested `<a>`, the problem is solved.

I suppose there is something to do with all of them

1. How angular load root component
2. How angular set the route
3. `<a>` handles its event bubbles
4. The new page load itself